# Qual a finalidade do atributo global contentEditable no elemento html?

Tags: html5

Em qual situação real ou quando será necessário o uso do atributo global contentEditable, pelo elemento html, visto que esse é um elemento raiz e que editá-lo seria o mesmo que modificar, inserir ou apagar os elementos folha? Exemplo:

```
<html contentEditable="true">
   ...
</html>
```

Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso quer dizer que é possivel editar/alterar o conteúdo do elemento.

O atributo `contentEditable` aceita 3 estados:

- "true" o conteúdo do elemento pode ser editado.
- "false" o conteúdo do elemento **não** pode ser editado.
- "inherit" indica que o estado é herdado do elemento ancestral que tenha esse atributo defenido.

O ultimo caso, combinado com o teu exemplo faz com que o conteúdo de elementos fique ou não editável dependendo de mudar num só lugar ([exemplo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOazbb)).

Mais informação (em Inglês) na [MDN: contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable)